# Override Magento 2 Catalog Bock Toolbar.php

Tags: magento2, toolbar

I'm trying to change change the default "sorter by"

I can't override 
*Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar*

I created a custom module, set the *di.xml* with

```
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" type="Custom\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" />
```

But I got this

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to 
Magento\\Catalog\\Block\\Product\\ListProduct::configureToolbar() must 
be an instance of 
Magento\\Catalog\\Block\\Product\\ProductList\\Toolbar, instance of 
Custom\\Catalog\\Block\\Product\\ProductList\\Toolbar given, called in 
/var/www/html/site/vendor/magento/module- 
catalog/Block/Product/ListProduct.php on line 206 and defined in 
/var/www/html/site/vendor/magento/module- 
catalog/Block/Product/ListProduct.php:488\nStack trace:\n#0 
/var/www/html/site/vendor/magento/module- 
catalog/Block/Product/ListProduct.php(206): 
Magento\\Catalog\\Block\\Product\\ListProduct- >configureToolbar(Object(Custom\\Catalog\\Block\\Product\\ProductList\\Toolbar), Object(WeltPixel\\LayeredNavigation\\Model\\ResourceModel\\Fulltext\\Collection\\Interceptor))\n#1 /var/www/html/site/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/ListProduct.php(467): Magento\\Catalog\\Block\\Product\\ListProduct->addToolbarBlock(Object(WeltPixel\\LayeredNavigation\\Model\\ResourceModel\\Fulltext\\Collection\\Interceptor))\n#2 /var/www/html/site/vendor/ma in /var/www/html/site/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/ListProduct.php on line 488,
```

Comment: hi @xdev I hope this one is related to the one you are asking https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/255507/sorting-and-sort-direction-applied-together/255903#255903

Comment: thank you, I just overrided the ListProduct.php

Comment: oh that's great! happy to know that.