# How to remove default options from sort order list?

Tags: filter, sorting, sort, product-sorting

How can I remove default options from de sort by list? For example, see the image? Is it possible to remove Best Sellers from the list?

[image]

Comment: You  // Remove specific default sorting options check this one https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/255507/sorting-and-sort-direction-applied-together/255903#255903